# Product Description showing at short description place

Tags: magento-1, product-attribute, product-view

My website is showing product short description at wrong place in product view page. Instead it is showing at place of Description tab.

Please help me out.

Comment: Please confirm whether u would like to show short description instead of description​ in the product view page

Comment: I want my default setting . Short description data to short description place and description to description box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update in xml. Go to `catalog_product_view.xml` of Catalog module. You can use `move` for this.

This can also be done by updating `default.xml` file of theme. You can choose any option and do changes in extended module not in core. Comment your progress and I will help to sort out this issue.

Comment: Can you please explain how and where should i look. I am not good in coding. Please guide me.

Comment: Path: vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml and vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml but dont edit in core files.

Comment: How to show additional description in short description section?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the product view page where that description part is coming. There can be change in attribute code which is calling that block.

Comment: I have used same theme at two different website but i get one website proper product short detail. But this website not showing short description. It is showing description instead of short description.

Comment: Have your problem solved ?